# ASP.NET MVC: 500 server internal error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, error-handling

I have deployed my application to server as below (from here):

To deploy an ASP.NET MVC application

1. In Visual Studio, open the project that you want to deploy.
2. In Solution Explorer, expand the References node.
3. Select the following assemblies:

   - System.Web.Mvc
   - System.Web.Routing
   - System.Web.Abstractions
4. In the Properties window, set Copy Local to True.
5. In Solution Explorer, right-click the project and click Publish.  The Publish Web dialog box is displayed.
6. In Target location (http:, ftp:, or disk path), browse to a local folder and click Open.
7. Select either Replace matching files with local copies or Delete all existing files prior to publish.
8. Under Copy, select one of the following, depending on your needs: Only files needed to run this application, All project files, or All files in the source project folder.
9. If your application contains files in the App_Data folder such as database files, select Include files from the App_Data folder.
10. Click Publish. All the files that are required in order to deploy the application are copied to the target folder.

Afterward I have errors connecting database which was about loging failure which fixed. Then I face `500 internal server error`.

I tried to enable debugging options and show errors which did not worked([here are the details](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37994682/1080355)).

I tried to do some **blind tries**, e.g. I created a control/view which its view just simply display an static output without any logic however it is still have 500 error.

I don't know how to fix this and how to continue debugging this project. What can I do know?

Comment: Add error logging to your app, and/or check the Windows event logs.

Comment: @mason it is hosted on a shared host and I have not access windows event logs. I used elmah for error logging but it is not working.

Comment: So? You don't need Elmah. In your global application class (global.asax or global.asax.cs) you'll see an `Application_Error` method (or you can add one). That will get called when there's an error in your app. Have it write to a file in `App_Data` or email you the error info.